# BaseController for HttpClient Instance

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have some API client to make request. Those are described in startup.

Simply, is it make sense to create HttpClient via base class and calling common request methods from base. Or each controller should create own client ? Is there will be a problem ?

Base

```
public class BaseController : ControllerBase
{
    public HttpClient client;
    public BaseController(IHttpClientFactory factory, string clientName)
    {
        client = factory.CreateClient(clientName);
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string query)
    {
    }
}
```

Foo

```
public class FooController : BaseController
{
    public FooController(IHttpClientFactory factory) : base(factory, "fooclient")
    {
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
    {
        return await Get($"Foo/Get/{id}");
    }
}
```

Comment: use this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @ViacheslavAvsenev Actually, I cannot see the part in that article related with my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing *technically* wrong with this approach, but it's preferable to use typed clients. The way that is done is by creating a "service" class which will own the client:

```
public class FooService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public FooService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpClient));
    }

    ...
}
```

Then, you register this in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddHttpClient<FooService>(c =>
{
    // configure your HttpClient
});
```

Finally, you inject this service class into your controller:

```
public class FooController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly FooService _fooService;

    public FooController(FooService fooService)
    {
        _fooService = fooService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fooService));
    }

    ...
}
```

This then serves to encapsulate your `HttpClient` logic. You simply add methods to the service to do things the controller needs and the service makes the actual `HttpClient` requests to do that. That makes it infinitely easier to change things if the API you're utilizing should change. You just change the service and you're good to go, instead of having to track down every place you used `HttpClient` to interact with this API, which is a much more difficult task.

Additionally, having the client be typed gives you the ability to configure it once for all, as well as add things like retry and exception handling policies in one place. Since the client is injected for a particular type (i.e. `FooService`) there's no magic strings for the client name that you could fat finger or otherwise mess up.

Comment: Thank you for better approach.